# XML tagname is a PHP function

Tags: php, xml, function, tags

I'm trying to parse an XML file in PHP with the `simplexml_load_file` function. Everything is fine, except my XML file has a `<TIME>` tag, which is a PHP function.

So the following code fails to get the tag value :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('some_xml_file.xml');
$value = $xml->SOME_TAG->TIME;
```

How do I get this value?

Comment: could you try to be more specific what kind of errors you get? because as far as i know, PHP would *not* try to execute the function time() in that case, since it does not have any parentheses (necessary for a function call). also, after a `->`, PHP looks for a member of the object, *not* a general function.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual:

> Accessing elements within an XML document that contain characters not
>   permitted under PHP's naming convention (e.g. the hyphen) can be
>   accomplished by encapsulating the element name within braces and the
>   apostrophe.
>
> Example #3 Getting

```
<?php
include 'example.php';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

echo $xml->movie->{'great-lines'}->line; // "PHP solves all my web problems"
?>
```

And if you need to get an attribute you can do this:

> So far, we have only covered the work of reading element names and
>   their values. SimpleXML can also access element attributes. Access
>   attributes of an element just as you would elements of an array.

```
foreach ($xml->movie[0]->rating as $rating) {
    switch((string) $rating['type'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<?php

$xmlString = "<top><middle><TIME>1:27</TIME></middle></top>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
echo $xml->middle->TIME;


php /tmp/xml.php 
1:27
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of your XML file. For your PHP code to work, it should AT LEAST contain this:

```
<XML>
<SOME_TAG>
   <TIME>1:27</TIME>
</SOME_TAG>
</XML>
```

When I use this XML file combined with your code, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I manage to get the value but there's still something strange.
XML example :

```
<INGREDIENTS>
   <INGREDIENT>
      <NAME>Potatoes</NAME>
      <AMOUNT>10 kg</AMOUNT>
      <TME>20 min</TIME>
   </INGREDIENT>
</INGREDIENTS>
```

PHP code to get NAME, AMOUNT and TIME values :

```
$ing = $xml->INGREDIENTS->INGREDIENT;
$name = $ing->NAME;
$amount= $ing->AMOUNT;
$time= $ing->TIME;
echo $name." / ".$amount." / ".$time;
```

Result :

```
Potatoes / 10 kg /
```

However, if I use the whole path to the TIME tag :

```
$ing = $xml->INGREDIENTS->INGREDIENT;
$name = $ing->NAME;
$amount= $ing->AMOUNT;
$time= $xml->INGREDIENTS->INGREDIENT->TIME;
echo $name." / ".$amount." / ".$time;
```

Result :

```
Potatoes / 10 kg / 20 min
```

Can anyone explain why it's working this way ?

Comment: Im on older PHP  5.4.25,  given your XML file example, this works for me:  `$xml = simplexml_load_file('some_xml_file.xml');
$ing =  $xml->INGREDIENT;
$name = $ing->NAME;
$amount= $ing->AMOUNT;
$time= $ing->TIME;`  So the answer would be: you need to use the right way to access the SimpleXMLObjects's properties...